# A riddle of anagrams

Tags: riddle, anagram

> I must get to the bottom of this
>   But it is so far away
>   It couldn't be further
>
> So I swap round to be a gardener
>   
> I hold up my plants
>   
> Holding the nutrients they need
>
> But I change again, my choice
>   From a range of possibilities
>   But I am the select

What was I and what do I change into?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is it:

> Top, pot, opt.
>  Top is the farthest away from bottom.
>  Pot hold a plant and its nutrition.
>  Opt is (thanks to @Will) to make a choice or decision.

Comment: The last one isn't necessarily short for anything. It's already a verb. Moreover, _choice from a range of possibilities_ is straight out of the dictionary.

Comment: @Will thanks, couldn't see it till you said it! Edited answer accordingly.

Comment: Correct! Well done to you too @Will