# A riddle of anagrams 2

Tags: riddle, anagram

Previous riddle of anagrams [here...](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30770/a-riddle-of-anagrams)

> I'm a hard worker,
> always producing
> But I'm a perfectionist and I
> throw all my produce out
>   
> Now I am with someone,
> Yet I am still an individual thing
>   
> And somehow new
>   
> I'll enter that in my account
>   
> I'm annoying you, that gets a tick
>   
> Although that is a little bit
>   
> I'm incredibly small
>   
> But beware, I can bite
>   
> You cant tell me who I am
>   
> But my mute friend with a face can
>   
> I am the 4th
>   
> But now I have got to go...

What are the anagrams?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it

> emit, item, mite, time?

I'm a hard worker,
always producing
But I'm a perfectionist and I
throw all my produce out

> emit?? throwing out all of your produce

Now I am with someone,
Yet I am still an individual thing 
And somehow new 
I'll enter that in my account

> Item: A couple is said to be an item, and a thing is an item, and in some games, you can have items in your account.

I'm annoying you, that gets a tick 
Although that is a little bit 
I'm incredibly small 
But beware, I can bite

> Mite: A very small insect like a tick that bites you.

You cant tell me who I am 
But my mute friend with a face can 
I am the 4th 
But now I have got to go...

> Time: Is always changing so saying a time will not be exact, a clock face tells time, it is the 4th dimension, it keeps running.

Comment: That is correct